# DSpace Migration from 3.5 to 6.2

Tags: solr, dspace

I'm migrating Dspace from version 3.5 to 6.2 and during the process two scripts crashed when the flyway is running:

- V6.0_2016.04.04__DS-3086-OAI-Performance-fix.sql
- V6.0_2016.07.21__DS-2775.sql

After I fix the problem, the migration works fine.

When I start tomcat everything seems to be right. Except for the exceptions below (for all assetstores, but the folder is empty. Because is very large):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dspace/assetstore/62/34/68/62346815873316363781278191609234408121 (No such file or directory)
org.dspace.discovery.SolrServiceImpl @ Wrote Item: 123/2334 to Index
```

The JSPUI appears with the names that I put in the local.cfg and shows my communities. But with the wrong link, for example:

- http://localhost:8080/jspui/handle/null

The link is repeated for all communities.

When I try to access a my communities with the correct link, the following message is displayed:

- http://localhost:8080/jspui/handle/123/3

> The identifier 123/3 does not correspond to a valid Object in DSpace. This
>   may be because of one of the following reasons:
>
> The URL of the current page is incorrect - if you followed a link from
>   outside of DSpace it may be mistyped or corrupt. You entered an
>   invalid ID into a form - please try again. If you're having problems,
>   or you expected the ID to work, feel free to contact the site
>   administrators.

I've already tried reindexing, re-updating, restoring the database and I can not progress.

It seems like a problem between Solr and Dspace because the information is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

try to change into V6.0_2015.03.07__DS-2701_Hibernate_migration.sql

> UPDATE handle SET resource_id = (SELECT community.uuid FROM community
>   WHERE handle.resource_legacy_id = community.community_id AND
>   handle.resource_type_id = 4); UPDATE handle SET resource_id = (SELECT
>   collection.uuid FROM collection WHERE handle.resource_legacy_id =
>   collection.collection_id AND handle.resource_type_id = 3); UPDATE
>   handle SET resource_id = (SELECT item.uuid FROM item WHERE
>   handle.resource_legacy_id = item.item_id AND handle.resource_type_id =
>   2);

with

> UPDATE handle SET resource_id = (SELECT community.uuid FROM community
>   WHERE handle.resource_legacy_id = community.community_id AND
>   handle.resource_type_id = 4) where handle.resource_type_id = 4; UPDATE
>   handle SET resource_id = (SELECT collection.uuid FROM collection WHERE
>   handle.resource_legacy_id = collection.collection_id AND
>   handle.resource_type_id = 3) where handle.resource_type_id = 3; UPDATE
>   handle SET resource_id = (SELECT item.uuid FROM item WHERE
>   handle.resource_legacy_id = item.item_id AND handle.resource_type_id =
>   2) where handle.resource_type_id = 2;

and migrate database again